# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Promise<unknown>'

Tags: http-post

Im having an issue on my code posting my input value to my json api. Please help how can i address this problem on Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Promise'.
Sorry im just a beginner here. Thanks in advance.

```js
//This is my code on component.ts
async OnNext() {
    let newCase = {PersonalInformation:{}, Status:"Pending", LastViewedPage:"personal-info", 
CreatedBy: this.User.userId}
    newCase.PersonalInformation = this.PersonalInformation.value
    const responseData = this.conn.CreateCase(newCase)
    if(responseData.id) {
      this.router.navigate(['address-info'])
    }else{
      this.errorDesc = "System error."
    }
  }
```

```html
//This is my post code in my service definition.
  async CreateCase(data: any) {
    return new Promise((success, failed) => {
      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/caseList', data).subscribe(
        data => {success(data)},
        error => {failed(error)}
      )
    })
  }
```

Comment: What is `this.http`? Does it take any generic type parameters that would describe what `data` is going to be? Also note you're shadowing the `data` parameter to `CreateCase`, which is confusing, and there's absolutely no need to create a `new Promise`, inside an `async` function, to wrap something that's _already a promise_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe im developing a multiple form posting the data into a new json api and allowing me to update the data anytime until it is submitted. Please explain more. Im starting to learn at this point. Thank you.